# menu nav stays not opened when clicked on a link in sidebar in bootstrap 3

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I have this code.When I clicka link in sidebar, it goes to the concerned link and the menu is closed. I want to be opened the link as well as the menu which i have clicked.
I'm designing a 70+ page site that uses a combination of multi-tiered sidebar menus and image maps for navigation, plus breadcrumbs in the navbar to keep track of where you're at.

I want to be able to:
1. open the submenu panels and display the list of menu options available;
2. highlight the menu tree option for the current page; and
3. add the appropriate link for the current page to the breadcrumb pat.

However, when I make a change to the sidebar (e.g., add or delete a menu option, change the grouping or order of the submenu items, etc.), I have to make the exact same change times 70! After 1 or 2 of these revisions, I'd rather not make any more changes!

```
<div id="sidebar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<!-- BEGIN Navlist -->
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li>
        <div class="admin_logo">
            <a href="index.php" class="viewSelect"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Inksand Logo"></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.php">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
            <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
            <span>Catalog</span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
        </a>
        <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
        <ul class="submenu">          
            <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Categories</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="add-category-master.php">Add Categories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-master.php">Manage Categories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>               
            <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Vendors</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right "></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="add-vendor-master.php">Add Vendors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="vendor-master.php">Manage Vendors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Products</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="add-product-master.php">Add Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="product-master.php">Manage Products</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END Submenu -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fa   fa-map-marker"></i>
            <span>Localization</span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
        </a>
        <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Countries</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="add-country-master.php">Add Countries</a></li>
                    <li><a href="country-master.php">Manage Countries</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>States</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="add-state-master.php">Add States</a></li>
                    <li><a href="state-master.php">Manage States</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Cities</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="add-city-master.php">Add Cities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="city-master.php">Manage Cities</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Areas</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="add-area-master.php">Add Areas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="area-master.php">Manage Areas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    <!-- 
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Misc</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                 BEGIN Submenu 
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="order-status-master.php">Order Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="payment-master.php">Payment</a> 
                </ul>
            </li>
    -->
        </ul>
        <!-- END Submenu -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fa  fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
            <span>Sales</span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
        </a>
        <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
        <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="order-master.php">Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="courier-master.php">Shipment</a></li>
            <li><a href="return-master.php">Return</a></li>
            <li><a href="payment-master.php">Payment</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END Submenu -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>
            <span>Stock</span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
        </a>
        <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="add-stock-master.php">Add Stock</a></li>
            <li><a href="stock-master.php">Manage Stock</a></li>
    <li><a href="garbage-stock-master.php">Manage Garbage</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END Submenu -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fa   fa-money"></i>
            <span>Tax</span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
        </a>
        <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href=add-tax-master.php>Add Tax</a></li>
            <li><a href=tax-master.php>Manage Tax</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END Submenu -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fa  fa-user"></i>
            <span>Customers</span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
        </a>
        <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="customer-master.php">Manage Customers</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END Submenu -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fa   fa-cog"></i>
            <span>Tools</span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
        </a>
        <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
        <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Banner</a></li>
            <li><a href="backup-master.php">Backup</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Setting</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END Submenu -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
            <span>Report</span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
        </a>
        <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
        <ul class="submenu">
    <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Sales</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="order-report.php">Order</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tax-report.php">Tax</a></li>
        <li><a href="shipping-report.php">Shipping</a></li>
        <li><a href="return-report.php">Return</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Products</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="product-report.php">Viewed</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Purchased</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Vendors</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="vendor-report.php">Vendor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">              
                    <span>Customers</span>
                    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></b>
                </a>
                <!-- BEGIN Submenu -->
                <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="customer-order-report.php">Order</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cart-report.php">Cart</a></li>
        <li><a href="wishlist-report.php">Wishlist</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END Submenu -->
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- END Navlist -->
<!-- BEGIN Sidebar Collapse Button -->
<div id="sidebar-collapse" class="visible-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
</div>
<!-- END Sidebar Collapse Button -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `active` class to item you want to be opened.

For example:

```
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="active"><a href="add-category-master.php">Add Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="category-master.php">Manage Categories</a></li>
            </ul>
```

top open Category menu and highlight "Add Categories" item.

Comment: no, you need a php code, for example. When you change page - your javascript app dies and new javascript app start